# File not opening in masm32

Tags: assembly, dos, masm32, 16-bit

My program asks for a filename to be read, then it should produce a clone of that file with the filename "Clone_originalfilename". This is my block of code:

```
.data
filename db 100 
         db ?
         db 100 dup (0)
copyfile db "Clone_", 0

.code
mov dx, offset filename ; reads the filename entered by user
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h

mov si, offset filename + 1 ; replaces the last character (Enter) to '$'
mov cl, [ si ] 
mov ch, 0      
inc cx 
add si, cx 
mov al, '$'
mov [ si ], al 

; concatenate "Clone_" to the filename 
lea si, filename
lea di, copyfile

L0: 
    cmp byte ptr [di], '_' 
    jz exL0
    inc di
    jmp L0
exL0:
    inc di 
    add si, 2 
    xor bx, bx 
L1:
    cmp byte ptr [si], 0    
    jz exL1
    mov bl, byte ptr [si]   
    mov byte ptr [di], bl

    inc si
    inc di
    jmp L1
exL1:
    inc di
    mov bl, byte ptr [si]       
    mov byte ptr [di], bl


mov dx, offset filename 
mov al, 2
mov ah, 3Dh
int 21h

mov handle, ax
jc erroropening
....
```

but whenever I execute it, the program proceeds to erroropening which displays that the file cannot be read, I think the problem's in the concatenation of the strings but I have no idea how to fix it. Sorry I'm a newbie here.

Comment: I would recommend stepping through the code with a debugger (even debug.exe or get a copy of turbo debugger td.exe) to observe what happens. Learning to use a debugger is a valuable skill.

Comment: If you are creating an EXE (not COM) program then you need to initialise the Data Segment (DS) when your program starts. Usually with `mov ax,@data` followed by `mov ds,ax`

Comment: Why title and tag <[tag:masm32]>?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of mistakes in the short snippet. Let's assume you've forgotten to copy

```
.model small
.stack 1000h
```

and

```
.code
start:

END start
```

then remains:

1. There is no initialization of `DS`:

   ```
   mov ax, @data
   mov ds, ax
   ```

   So at least `lea di, copyfile` won't load the correct address. `filename` was stored at the wrong place.
2. You don't "*concatenate "Clone_" to the filename*" but vice versa. For that purpose you don't have enough space after `copyfile db "Clone_", 0`.
3. You replace the last character of the input with '$' but test the string afterwards for null (`cmp byte ptr [si], 0`).
4. In a DOS environment you can handle only with [8.3 filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). I'm betting your filename *Clone_...* is too long.
5. On `offset filename` you won't find a filename but the begin of the input structure of [`int 21h/ah=0Ah`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm).

Comment: For point #5 you could add a reference to something like Ralph Brown's interrupt list for [int 21h/ah=0ah](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) . I'd up vote then.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Done :-). I guess the OP should have known that, because `filename` is defined like a structure and the concatenation starts with `lea si, filename...add si, 2`.

Comment: Unless he was copying and pasting snippets of code from around the internet and didn't have any idea how it worked ;-)

Comment: I didn't include the others I just decided to out the snippet where I think my code has been wrong.